# Why do I sometimes get Key Error using SQS client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, botocore

I am using boto3 SQS client to receive messages from AWS SQS FIFO queue.

```
def consume_msgs():
    sqs = None
    try:
        sqs = boto3.client('sqs',
                       region_name=S3_BUCKET_REGION,
                       aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                       aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    except Exception:
        logger.warning('SQS client error {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())

  ### more code to process message
```

The application is set up as service on EC2 using `upstart`. It works fine most of time. But sometimes when I restart the service after code change, the app would exit with the following error

```
2018-10-06 01:29:38,654 WARNING SQS client error <class 'KeyError'>
2018-10-06 01:29:38,658 WARNING SQS client error <class 'KeyError'>
2018-10-06 01:29:38,663 ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/aae_client/app/run.py", line 194, in consume_msgs
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
  File "/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 83, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 851, in create_client
    endpoint_resolver = self.get_component('endpoint_resolver')
  File "/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 726, in get_component
    return self._components.get_component(name)
  File "/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 926, in get_component
    del self._deferred[name]
KeyError: 'endpoint_resolver'
```

Restarting the service usually fixes it. It doesn't happen every time I restart the service. What is confusing is the `KeyError` warning leading the actual error traceback. What exactly does this `KeyError` refer to? It can't be the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` since this key is never changed and it works just fine most of the time. The issue happens quite randomly and comes and goes. Therefore it is hard to debug. And I don't understand how this error escaped the `try..except` block

### EDIT

Based on comments, this seem to be related to multithreading. `consume_msg` is indeed run by multiple threads
def process_msgs():

```
for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=consume_msgs, name='worker-%s' % i)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(MAIN_PROCESS_SLEEP_INTERVAL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [github issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/801) suggests you should set the sqs  client in the top-level once (rather than in the function):

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs',
                   region_name=S3_BUCKET_REGION,
                   aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                   aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)


def consume_msgs():
    # code to process message
```

Comment: This [issue mentions the same thing](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1592) / same solution.

Comment: `consume_msg` is run by multiple threads (see my new edits). Moving `sqs client` out of this function will have it ended up in the main thread. Well each thread still needs its own sqs client, right?

Comment: The link you provided did suggest creating `session` for each thread instead of having the clients sharing the same session. Something like `boto3.Session().client`.

Comment: @ddd I think you're misreading that, or - at least - some comments suggest putting it at the top-level (and in the main thread) if you're using threading.

Comment: You could also move the polling to the main thread and have only the processing on the worker threads. It sounds like multiple sqs clients and threads is a bad combination for boto3 (likely buggy).

Answer (score 15):

Maybe I misunderstand some of the other answers, but in the case of multithreaded execution, I don't think that having one boto3 client object and passing it to other functions will work if those functions are executed in separate threads.  I've been experiencing sporadic `endpoint_resolver` errors invoking a boto3 client service, and they were stopped by following the example in the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-multiprocessing) and the comments on boto3 GitHub issues such as [#1246](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1246) and [#1592](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1592), and creating a separate session object in each thread.  In my case, it meant an almost trivial change in my code, going from

```
client = boto3.client(variant, region_name = creds['region_name'],
                      aws_access_key_id = ...,
                      aws_secret_access_key = ...)
```

to

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(variant, region_name = creds['region_name'],
                        aws_access_key_id = ...,
                        aws_secret_access_key = ...)
```

in the function that is executed in separate threads. My reading of the OP's code for `consume_msgs()` is that a similar change could be made and it would eliminate the occasional `endpoint_resolver` error.

Comment: In fact only creating a boto client isn't thread safe. Using one client in separate threads is ok. On the other hand using same resource and session in separate threads is not thread safe. Another catch: creating a session in each thread is quite time consuming. You can find multithreaded client example in [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-clients)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when creating a client for S3 but AFAIK it is the same issue.
There's non-thread-safe code that is used in the process of creating a client:

```
        if name in self._deferred:
            factory = self._deferred[name]
            self._components[name] = factory()
            # Only delete the component from the deferred dict after
            # successfully creating the object from the factory as well as
            # injecting the instantiated value into the _components dict.
            del self._deferred[name]
```

(from botocore/session.py in the get_component method - that is the code that raises the KeyError when trying to delete a key that was deleted by a different thread)

Locking the client creation solved it for me (as suggested in https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/806)